# Number of initial conditions required for a pair of multivariable recursion relations

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions, recursion, recursive-algorithms

I have the following pair of recursion relations for $f_{m,n}$, featuring two indices/variables $(m,n)$:

$$\sin{\left(\frac{n \hbar}{2} \right)} f_{m+1,n} - \sin{\left(\frac{m \hbar}{2} \right)} f_{m,n+1} + \sin{\left(\frac{(m-n) \hbar}{2} \right)} f_{m-1,n-1} = 0 ,$$
$$\cos{\left(\frac{n \hbar}{2} \right)} f_{m+1,n} + \cos{\left(\frac{m \hbar}{2} \right)} f_{m,n+1} + \cos{\left(\frac{(m-n) \hbar}{2} \right)} f_{m-1,n-1} = E f_{m,n} . $$
In the above, $m$ and $n$ are integers, while $E$ and $\hbar$ are real constants. I am looking to use/generate the $f_{m,n}$ for $m,n \geq 0$ in the work I am doing, but generally $m,n$ can be positive and negative.

Given the trigonometric nature of the coefficients of the $f$'s, I expect that it may be difficult to find an analytic solution to these relations. I have seen that generating functions can potentially be used to solve multivariable equations like these, but what I would really like to know first is, is there an algorithmic way of counting how many initial conditions are required to generate all possible $f_{m,n}$ from these relations? Additionally, are there set values of $(m,n)$ which *must be* used as initial conditions/data? For example, must $f_{1,1} = c$, where $c$ is a constant, form an initial condition for some reason?

I cite these equations from equation (3.5) of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.08442). Here the authors use symmetry properties (coming from physics) of the $f_{m,n}$ which reduces complexity and means very few initial data are needed (i.e. they only need an initial condition for $f_{1,1}$). I wanted to do this without any of the additional symmetry properties.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: When you say "I prefer to use positive exclusively", how do you want me to interpret the relations in the case $m = 1$ or $n = 1$?  (If by "positive" you mean "nonnegative", please replace $1$ with $0$ in that question.)

Comment: Also it looks to me like the behavior of this system will depend on whether $\hbar$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$; what do you want/prefer/expect?

Comment: Hi @JBL. By positive exclusively, I really just meant that i need the $f_{m,n}$ at $m,n \geq 0$ for my purposes. In this sense, I think non-negative $m,n$ is sufficient for what I have in mind. 

I ran some Mathematica code for $m,n \geq 0$ and by additionally using $m = n$ in the first equation, to generate relation $f_{a, 1+a} = f_{a+1,a}$, was able to solve/obtain all $f_{m,n}$ in terms of initial data set $A =\{f_{0,0}, f_{1,0}, f_{1,1} \}$. This is OK, but it was a bit arbitrary. I chose the size and members of $A$ as a guess.

I want $\hbar$ to not be a multiple of $\pi$. Thanks.

Comment: You haven't understood my question.  Suppose we're talking about $m, n \geq 0$.  How do you want me to interpret the relations when I plug in $m = 0$ or $n = 0$?    (There is an $f_{m - 1, n - 1}$ term that is problematic.)

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure what you mean by interpret then? I see that for $m=0$ or $n=0$ we get terms like in the following set $B= \{ f_{-1,n}, f_{m,-1}, f_{-1,-1} \}$ but these are defined in terms of the $f_{m,n}$ with $m,n \geq 0$, no? I am not saying these terms in $B$ cannot/should not be present, Its just I only require the $f_{m,n}$ with $m,n \geq 0$. For example, $f_{0,-1} = f_{1,1}$ from the first relation, so the terms in set $B$ can be related to those in my previous $A$. Perhaps you prefer to take $(m,n) \to (m+1,n+1)$ then we would only need find the $f_{m,n}$ for $m,n \geq 0$?

Comment: "no?"  I don't know, that's what I'm asking you.  Suppose I take as the domain of $f$ the set $\{(m, n) \colon m, n \geq 0\}$.  Then the symbol $f_{-1, -1}$ is not defined.  What do you want me to do with the relations that include this symbol?  You are saying "well define them using the relations" and I am saying please be precise about what exactly you mean.  Shifting by 1 doesn't help; then we say the domain is $\{(m, n) \colon m, n \geq 1\}$ but there are relations involving $f_{0, 0}$, and this isn't defined.

Comment: In general, it need not be the case that a recurrence satisfied on a subset can be extended to also be satisfied on a larger set.  You say you're interested in the domain $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ rather than $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ -- sure, sounds good, but please tell me exactly what the set of relations is that you want $f$ to satisfy when I take its domain to be that quarter-plane.

Comment: If I want to study the functions $f$ defined on $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ that satisfy $f_{n} = f_{n - 1} + f_{n - 2}$, what I need to say (if I'm being precise) is that $f_n = f_{n - 1} + f_{n - 2}$  **for $n \geq 2$**.  In some contexts people want to do something different at the boundary, not just delete relations that cross over it -- but one needs to be explicit about what that different thing is.  (The Fibonacci relation is simple and can always be extended to all of $\mathbb{Z}$ -- but that's not automatic for other recurrences.)

Comment: I apologise for not being precise. What I meant by a shift was shift the equations $(m,n) \to (m+1, n+1)$ and then choose domain $(m, n) \geq 0$. That way every $f_{m,n}$ is defined for every choice of $(m,n)$. I can't see a problem with this on my end (i.e. I used this idea in my project and got the same/expected results pre-shift), but perhaps there is a reason this cannot be done? 

Also, say we remove any additional restrictions and set $(m,n)$ in domain $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, do you have perhaps have an idea about the initial data then?

Comment: Okay, great, thanks.  I will think about it.  (I've played around with a few ideas that did not work out as I was expecting; if I come up with anything concrete, I will report back.)